# How does this SwiftUI binding + state example manage to work without re-invoking body?

Tags: swift, swiftui

A coworker came up with the following SwiftUI example which *looks* like it works just as expected (you can enter some text and it gets mirrored below), but *how* it works is surprising to me!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Change the string", text: $text)
            WrappedText(text: $text)
        }
    }
}

struct WrappedText: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
    }
}
```

My newbie mental model of SwiftUI led me to think that typing in the TextField would change the `$text` binding, which would in turn mutate the `text` @State var. This would then invalidate the `ContentView`, triggering a fresh invocation of `body`. But interestingly, that's not what happens! Setting a breakpoint in ContentView's `body` only gets hit once, while WrappedText's `body` gets run every time the binding changes. And yet, as far as I can tell, the `text` state really is changing.

So, what's going on here? Why doesn't SwiftUI re-invoke ContentView's body on every change to `text`?

Comment: FWIW, WWDC 2021’s [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022) and 2023’s [Demystify SwiftUI performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10160) are good primers on the SwiftUI view lifecycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On State change SwiftUI rendering engine at first checks for equality of views inside body and, if some of them not equal, calls body to rebuild, but only those non-equal views. In your case no one view depends (as value) on `text` value (`Binding` is like a reference - it is the same), so nothing to rebuild at this level. But inside `WrappedText` it is detected that `Text` with new `text` is not equal to one with old `text`, so body of `WrappedText` is called to re-render this part.

This is declared rendering optimisation of SwiftUI - by checking & validating exact changed view by equality.

By default this mechanism works by `View` struct properties, but we can be involved in it by confirming our view to `Equatable` protocol and marking it `.equatable()` modifier to give some more complicated logic for detecting if `View` should be (or not be) re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `text`'s `@State` getter was not called anywhere in `body` so SwiftUI does not track any dependency, i.e. there is no need to call `body` when `text` is set.

FYI `$text` is sugar for `Binding(get: { }, set: { })`, i.e. a pair of closures, thus the `text`'s `@State` getter is not called when you declare `$text` and no dependency is tracked.

If you wanted to force `body` to be called for some reason, you could fake a call to the getter with:

```
var body: some View {
    let _ = text
    ...
```

Now the dependency will be tracked and `body` will be called if a text is updated via a binding in child `View`. If you find yourself needing this then normally it means the `@State` was placed in the wrong `View`, it should be placed in a common parent of everywhere it is used.